# Scale and size of plot in RStudio shiny

Tags: r, size, rstudio, shiny

Related, but only talks about the allocated plot space in general, not how to directly set the plot image size and *then* scale it to fill the desired space

- [Shiny Chart Space Allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204735/shiny-chart-space-allocation)

---

I'm creating a shiny web app and would like to set the size of the plot *and* scale. What I mean by that is I'm looking for a way to set a finite height/width for my plot, and *then* scale that set sized image to the `mainPanel( plotOutput ())` area.

Take this as an example/analogous situation outside of `shiny`.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x^2
png("~/Desktop/small.png", width = 600, height = 400)
plot(x, y)
dev.off()

png("~/Desktop/big.png", width = 1200, height = 800)
plot(x, y)
dev.off()
```

I can't upload images to SO and set a size, so I'll include a browser screenshot of each using the following html:

```
<img src="file:///home/jwhendy/Desktop/file.png" width = "800px" />
```

This is a full width screenshot on my 1600 x 900 px laptop.

**Small**
[image: smaller picture]

**Big**
[image: bigger picture]

I'd like to control the size of the image itself, as I find the `ggplot2` legends when using options like `colour = var` and `size = var` to be pretty small. Note the difficulty of reading axis labels for the bigger picture as well. I realize I may get into a situation where the size of the image doesn't scale well due to limited pixels, but I think I at least have *some* room to travel before I run into that.

Any suggestions? I've tried playing with the following so far, but without luck:

### **ui.R**

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

headerPanel("Title"),

  sidebarPanel(),

  mainPanel(

     plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", width = "100%"))

  ))
```

### **server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  x <- 1:10
  y <- x^2

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({

    plot(x, y) }, height = 400, width = 600 )
} )
```

It seems that the height/width options specified in `server.R` override whatever I have set in the `plotOutput` section of `ui.R`.

Is there a way to keep the size of the plot image smaller to maintain readability while still filling the desired `mainPanel` area?

Comment: A better approach is to control the size of the plotted points and text, rather than trying to do it through image sizing. Have you tried setting the `cex` options?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Not sure if this gives you fully what you desire, but here's what worked for me.

The options specified in `Server.R` did take effect. (I just plotted two graphs of different sizes each.) I also took @Manetheran's suggestion and made cex and cex.axis into parameters. They seem to be working.

Below is the code for the full app, plus one screen shot.

```
###UI.R
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(


  headerPanel("Title"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput(inputId = "opt.cex",
            label = "Point Size (cex)",                            
                min = 0, max = 2, step = 0.25, value = 1),
  sliderInput(inputId = "opt.cexaxis",
              label = "Axis Text Size (cex.axis)",                            
              min = 0, max = 2, step = 0.25, value = 1) 
),
        
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot",  width = "100%"),
    plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot2", width = "100%")
  )
))
        

###Server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  x <- 1:10
  y <- x^2
    
  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({    
    plot(x, y)}, height = 200, width = 300)


  output$main_plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(x, y, cex=input$opt.cex, cex.lab=input$opt.cexaxis) }, height = 400, width = 600 )
} )
```

[image]

#### Update re. the Width=100% option in `UI.R`

Yes, in my case it definitely makes a difference. In the two lines below, new_main_plot and new_main_plot2 are identical, but they were rendered with different sizes. So the `width` option does take effect.

```
 mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = "new_main_plot",  width = "100%"),
    plotOutput(outputId = "new_main_plot2", width = "25%")
  )
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does the `width = 100%` option do anything in `ui.R`, in your opinion? It looks like it's just going to be the size specified in `renderPlot()`, regardless? Either way, I think this will work. I used the `plot()` command from `base`, but in reality use `ggplot2` (didn't anticipate a `plot`-specific solution. I think [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528161/cex-equivalent-in-ggplot2) will allow me to do the same. A bit more typing... but I think it should work. Thanks!

Comment: @Hendy Updated my response. Yes, width does make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out (I should have just done that). I did a bunch of quick combinations and used inspect element to see what they were doing in the resultant html. I edited my answer with the results to help others looking into this. Thanks again!

Comment: is it possible that the width or height of the plot adjusts automatically to the window size?

Answer (score 24):

@Ram's answer works great for the `base` plotting utility.

Just to expand for other passers-by, to do this with ggplot:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
p <- p + theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 20)) # tweak size = n until content
print(p)
```

At least something to that effect, depending on what you want. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528161/cex-equivalent-in-ggplot2) for the basic idea, though please refer to the current [ggplot2 0.9.3](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/theme.html) documentation about setting text options -- you can specify axis text, legend text, facet_grid strip text, etc.

Since the previous SO question, the specification has changed from `opts([option] = theme_text(size = n))` to `theme([option] = element_text(size = n))`. It will probably change again... so just find the current test/theme/options page for `ggplot2`.

---

I played around a bit further based on @Ram's followup and think I understand how `ui.R` and `server.R` interact setting different options and looking at the `Inspect element` in Chromium.

ui.R sets the available plot area one can fill, and server.R defines the plot size.

- `ui.R:` width = 100%, `server.R`: no options set

[image]

- `ui.R:` width = 100%, `server.R`: width = 800, height = 600

[image]

- `ui.R:` width = 50%, `server.R`: width = 800, height = 600

[image]

- `ui.R:` width = 200%, `server.R`: width = 800, height = 600

[image]

The last one was all I needed to see in order to answer the question definitively. If you replicate the settings, you will see that the plot area `<div>` is indeed 200% of the screen width and creates a horizontal scroll bar in the browser... however the image is still at it's fixed size.

You *can* however, generate an image larger than the plot area (in pixels) and then scale it down via `ui.R` and specifying a `width = n %` option.

So... I cannot create a smaller image in pixels (which creates larger text size relative to the overall plot) and then make it bigger to have bigger text. One does, indeed, need to create a graph the size of the plot area (or larger) and scale the text to satisfaction via the plot (or ggplot) command itself.

One also cannot specify, at least at present, a % for the width in `server.R`, presumably because it passes the height/width options to the `png()` command to generate the image. You'll get an error trying to do that (but it was worth a shot).

I disagree that specifying the text size options is an easier route than what I was looking for, but at least I have something that works. I do the "cheating" way all the time for LaTeX documents with `pdf("file.pdf", width = 8, height = 6)`, create my plot, and then scale it however I want when including it in the .tex file. Much simpler, in my opinion, than futzing with `theme(axis.text = element_text(size = x))` for every plot.

Answer (score 0):

consider using '+ theme_bw(22)' to avoid changing individual text elements.

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware one could do this. You might consider adding some additional details for those (like me) who would have to [look up](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html) what argument the 22 is being passed to... I presume this is equivalent to `+ theme_bw(base_size = 22)`?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a `ggplot2` solution I got a workaround that seems to make it. Instead of `renderPlot()` one can use `renderImage()` and change the expression a bit.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(
    inputId = "n",
    "Sample size",
    value = 25
  ),
  imageOutput(outputId = "hist")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$hist <- renderImage({
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png") # create a temp file

    df <- data.frame(Z = rnorm(input$n))
    plot <- ggplot(df, aes(Z)) +
      geom_histogram()

    ggsave( # save the file
      outfile,
      plot = plot, # if you use native pipe |> save the plot to a variable; do not pipe it into ggsave() because |> doesn't work well with +
      device = "png",
      width = 1200,
      height = 700,
      units = "px",
      dpi = 72
    )

    list( # return a list with the <img> attributes
      src = outfile,
      alt = "Alternative text"
    )
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```