# Scaling shiny plots to window height

Tags: r, shiny

I want to scale a shiny plot to the height of the window.  This [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838709/scale-and-size-of-plot-in-rstudio-shiny) only uses absolute height specifications in pixels, when a `height = 100%` would be preferable.  I note in the documentation that `absolutePanel` can achieve this with its `top, bottom, left, right` arguments, but then you lose the side panel, and in any case the plot (while scaling to width) seems to ignore available height.

I'm guessing this relates to the html quirk that means you need to get the height with javascript `innerHeight` variable.  But I'm unclear how to implement a solution in shiny to get `ui.R` to utilise this.  Grateful for any pointers.

A basic app model for development:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(1000))
    })
  }
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("window height check"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("myplot")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use CSS3. Declare your height in viewport units http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units . 
You should be able to declare them using the `height` argument in `plotOutput` however `shiny::validateCssUnit` doesnt recognise them so you can instead declare them in a style header:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(server= function(input, output) {
    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
      hist(rnorm(1000))
    })
  }
  , ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("window height check"),
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$head(tags$style("#myplot{height:100vh !important;}"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("myplot")
    )
  )
  )
)
```

This wont work in the shiny browser but should work correctly in a main browser.

[image]

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but since I'm using `navbarPage` I can't seem to get the CSS to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179621/how-can-i-display-my-plot-without-toolbars-in-shiny

Comment: I was trying this approach but there's a `height = 400px` added in the plots which seems to override the height I specify in the `tag` function. Any clues?

Comment: Just to save someone who doesn't know much CSS: If you have multiple tabs, then use the CSS class `shiny-plot-output` rather than the ID i.e. like `tags$head(tags$style(".shiny-plot-output{height:100vh !important;}"))` for this setting to apply to all tabs