# Shinydashboard tabBox to fill mainPanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there a simple way to get the following `tabBox` to span the entire height of the `dashboardBody`?

```
app_ui <- function() {

    shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
      shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(title = "Baseball Statistics"),
      
      shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
        width = 250
      ),
      
      shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
        shinydashboard::box(title = "Individual"),
        shinydashboard::tabBox(title = "Stats",
                               shiny::tabPanel("Batting", DT::DTOutput("batting")),
                               shiny::tabPanel("Pitching", DT::DTOutput("pitching")),
                               shiny::tabPanel("Fielding", DT::DTOutput("fielding"))
                               )
      )
    )
}
```

I would like the `datatable` to occupy as much vertical screen as possible:

[image: screenshot]

The following answer was not successful - [Shinydashboard Tabbox Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872980/shinydashboard-tabbox-height)

I attempted to integrate the above answer by:

```
      shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
        shinydashboard::box(title = "Individual"),
        shinydashboard::tabBox(title = "Stats",
                               shiny::tags$head(
                                 shiny::tags$style(shiny::HTML(" #tabBox { height:90vh !important; } "))
                               ),
                               id="tabBox",
                               shiny::tabPanel("Batting", DT::DTOutput("batting")),
                               shiny::tabPanel("Pitching", DT::DTOutput("pitching")),
                               shiny::tabPanel("Fielding", DT::DTOutput("fielding"))
                               )
      )
```

The output looks like:

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Have you already tried this work around? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872980/shinydashboard-tabbox-height

Comment: Yes I have, it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Hmm ok, for me it worked, can you show me how you tried to integrate it?

Comment: Added above in edit.

Comment: I added my answer below, maybe we can come closer to a solution

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the oter DT options.

When I use only `scrollX` options

```r
  output$batting <- renderDT(iris, 
                             options = list( scrollX = TRUE))
```

I get [image]

Comment: So how can you add in scrollbars to the DT so you can scroll to parts of the data that are cut off?

Comment: eg.: output$dataset <- DT::renderDT(dataframes$df.response,
    options = list(
      scrollX = TRUE,
      lengthMenu = c(15, 50, 100, 200, 500),
      colReorder = list(realtime = FALSE)
   )
  ) with scrollX

Comment: Perfect, that adds a horizontal scrollbar. Now it's only running way off the bottom of the page, especially when I select show 100 rows. Is there a way to limit the vertical extension?

Comment: I edited to add scrolling and paging. With paging it can not span further than pagelength

Answer (score 0):

This is my final try, it seems the other things didn't work out, so:

```
  output$dataset <- DT::renderDT(dataframes$df.response,
    callback = JS(js),
    filter = "top",
    rownames = FALSE,
    selection = list(target = "row+column"),
    extensions = c("ColReorder"),
    options = list(
      # scrollX = TRUE,
      # lengthMenu = c(15, 50, 100, 200, 500),
      # colReorder = list(realtime = FALSE),
      pageLength = 1000,
      scrollY=TRUE
   )
  )
```

the `pagelength` element to the max rows of your data set it will show it entirely when loading. like in this screen:[image: lasttry]. Is this a possible workaround for you?

Comment: Yes, I get that weird extra tab with no title. And I also don't see your data set.

Comment: Ok i can see the data now and have no weird empty panel however Datatable is atm not scaling

Comment: I may have a last workaround to show you that could help you

Comment: I updated my answer and you can see the entire dataset rows from the beginning spanning, can this be a possible workaround for you? In my example it spanned the whole screen and i had to scroll a lot scrolly=TRUE