# Plot does not resize 100% width after show/hide sidebar in R shiny page

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a plot which is set to 100% width (default) in the main panel of a two-panel page in R Shiny. The sidebar is hideable through a toggle action button.

When the sidebar is visible (default), the plot fills the width of the main panel. When the sidebar is hidden, I want the plot to expand to fill 100% of the space now available, i.e. the whole browser window. But this does not happen! It keeps the same size.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

UI <- fluidPage(
    bsButton("showpanel", "Show/hide sidebar", type = "toggle", value = TRUE),
    sidebarLayout(
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.showpanel == true",
                         sidebarPanel("This is my sidebar.")
                         ),
        mainPanel(plotOutput("plot", width = "100%"))
        )
    )

SERVER <- function(input, output) {
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
        plot(1:10, main = "The width of this plot adjusts\nto window resizes but not to\nshow/hide sidepanel!")
    })
}

runApp(shinyApp(UI,SERVER))
```

Attempted so far:

- Defining the plot object from within the UI file, as above.
- Defining the plot object from within the server file, as a renderUI object.
- Set CSS tag in the page as per `tags$head(tags$style("#myplot{height:100vh !important;}"))` from this question, [Scaling shiny plots to window height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782041/scaling-shiny-plots-to-window-height).

Possible work-arounds:

- Make the width of the plot dynamic and depending on the state of the toggle button. Then I can make the plot e.g. 140% width when the sidebar is hidden. This does not generalise well, and loses the point of using the adaptability of `fluidPage`.

(`fluidPage` changes the layout dependent on the browser window size. For example, if you make your browser window about the size of a mobile phone, it will place the sidebar above the main panel.)

Comment: The problem is that using the sidebarLayout you create two bootstrap columns one with class `col-sm-4` for the sidebar and one with class `col-sm-8` for the plot this is why your plot wont re-size to larger than ~66% of the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a reactive layout (there are many questions on this eg [Switch between layouts reactively with shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137546/switch-between-layouts-reactively-with-shiny)). In your case that would be something like

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

UI <- shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
            bsButton("showpanel", "Show/hide sidebar", type = "toggle", value = TRUE),
            uiOutput('ui')
        )
    )

SERVER <- function(input, output) {

    output$ui <- renderUI({
        if (input$showpanel) {
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel("This is my sidebar."),
                mainPanel(plotOutput('plot'))
            )
        } else {
            plotOutput('plot')
        }
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        plot(1:10, main = "The width of this plot adjusts\nto window resizes and to\nshow/hide sidepanel!")
    })
}

runApp(shinyApp(UI,SERVER))
```

Comment: Works perfectly - thanks! Also has the benefit of keeping basically all of my code in one file. I just wasn't thinking outside of the box...

Answer (score 8):

@konvas answer is really good and probably the way you wan't to do this but if you want to use the `sidebarLayout` (and for the sake of giving another answer) you can use jQuery to toggle the bootstrap columns like:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      HTML("
            $(document).ready(function(){
              // Mark columns we want to toggle
              $('body').find('div [class=col-sm-4]').addClass('sidebarPanel');
              $('body').find('div [class=col-sm-8]').addClass('mainPanel');
            })


            Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler ('resize',function (message) {
              $('.sidebarPanel').toggle();
              $('.mainPanel').toggleClass('col-sm-8 col-sm-12');
              $(window).trigger('resize')
            });

           ")
    )
  ),
  actionButton("showpanel", "Show/hide sidebar"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("This is my sidebar."),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot", width = "100%"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$showpanel,{
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'resize', message = 1)

  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(1:10, main = "The width of this plot adjusts\nto window resizes but not to\nshow/hide sidepanel!")
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui,server))
```

The same methodology would apply if you use columns in a `fluidRow` or something similar.

Comment: Also a great answer, I don't have much experience with Java but this is what I was expecting the solution to be. Went with @konvas answer for reasons of parsimony. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I think his answer is really good, Glad I could help anyway!