# Switch between layouts reactively with shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

How can I switch between page layouts in Shiny in response to user input?  For example, I would like to switch between a sidebar layout to a wellpanel layout in order to have the graphics be able to span the entire page.

What I have so far seems to be on the verge of working, but I think the issue is that I can't reuse interfaces created from `renderUI`.  Here is an example,

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
            radioButtons('layout', 'Layout:', choices=c('Sidebar', 'WellPanel'), inline=TRUE),
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.layout == 'Sidebar'",
                uiOutput('sidebarUI')
            ),
            conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.layout == 'WellPanel'",
                uiOutput('wellUI')
            )
        )
    ),
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
        output$sidebarUI <- renderUI({
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    uiOutput('ui')
                ),
                mainPanel(
                    plotOutput('plot')
                )
            )
        })

        output$wellUI <- renderUI({
            fluidRow(
                column(12, plotOutput('plot')),
                column(12, wellPanel(uiOutput('ui')))
            )
        })

        output$ui <- renderUI({
            list(
                checkboxInput('inp1', 'Some stuff'),
                sliderInput('inp2', 'Some more stuff', 0, 10, 5)
            )
        })

        output$plot <- renderPlot({ plot(1) })
    })
)
```

If either one of the conditional panels is commented out, then the other one works, but only one will work with both conditional panels.  How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can't call an output twice (or more) in the ui, that's why this isn't working, instead you can do all the work in the server like this :

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      radioButtons('layout', 'Layout:', choices=c('Sidebar', 'WellPanel'), inline=TRUE),
      uiOutput('general_ui')
    )
  ),
  shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$general_ui <- renderUI({
      if (input$layout == "Sidebar") {
        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput('ui')
          ),
          mainPanel(
            plotOutput('plot')
          )
        )
      } else if (input$layout == "WellPanel") {
        fluidRow(
          column(12, plotOutput('plot')),
          column(12, wellPanel(uiOutput('ui')))
        )
      }
    })

    output$ui <- renderUI({
      list(
        checkboxInput('inp1', 'Some stuff'),
        sliderInput('inp2', 'Some more stuff', 0, 10, 5)
      )
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({ plot(1) })
  })
)
```

But there's a catch, when you switch between layout, the input widgets are reinitialized...

But you can fix it with something like this :

```
output$ui <- renderUI({
  list(
    checkboxInput('inp1', 'Some stuff'),
    if (is.null(input$inp2)) {
      sliderInput('inp2', 'Some more stuff', 0, 10, 5)
    } else {
      sliderInput('inp2', 'Some more stuff', 0, 10, input$inp2)
    }
  )
})
```

Before creating your widget, you'll have to check if the value already exists, in a more compact way than above you can do that :

```
output$ui <- renderUI({
      list(
        checkboxInput(inputId = "inp1", label = 'Some stuff', value = input$inp1 %||% FALSE),
        sliderInput(inputId = "inp2", label = 'Some more stuff', min = 0, max = 10, value = input$inp2 %||% 5)
      )
    })
```

With `%||%` function defined like this :

```
`%||%` <- function(a, b) {
  if (!is.null(a)) a else b
}
```

Comment: I can imagine that your UI is more complicated. You can probably write a function for validate a widget. I'll look into it later.