# Plot height of CA

Tags: r, ca

I am rendering CA plot in Shiny using FactoMineR package. While the plot renders nicely, the height of the plot seem to be fixed and it looks constricted. The reproducible data is as follows:

```
structure(list(MUMBAI = c(5236L, 222L, 24L, 54L, 31L), DELHI = c(4243L, 
301L, 54L, 67L, 107L), KOLKATTA = c(2777L, 67L, 270L, 64L, 56L
), HYDERABAD = c(3155L, 101L, 9L, 58L, 32L), PUNE = c(2262L, 
496L, 9L, 27L, 38L)), .Names = c("MUMBAI", "DELHI", "KOLKATTA", 
"HYDERABAD", "PUNE"), row.names = c("LOCAL CLIENT", "PRIVATE BUILDERS", 
"GOVERNMENT", "HONDA MOTORCYCLE AND SCOOTER INDIA PVT LTD", "PRIVATE COMPANIES"
), class = "data.frame")
```

The following is the code that I am using:

```
res <- CA(ft2, graph = FALSE)
plot(res, autoLab = "yes")
```

I have tried using

```
par(pin = c(10,4))
```

Changing the pin values, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Would this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838709/scale-and-size-of-plot-in-rstudio-shiny) help ?

Comment: From what package is `CA`? I found `ca`, but it's lower-case ...

Comment: @steveb many thanks....passing height and width within renderPlot really helped.  Many thanks again.