# Scale ggplot output in Shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, shiny

I'm having trouble shrinking my plotOutput. All I want to do is slightly shrink the ggplot so there is a little padding in the box.

This is the image I have:

[image]

This is the image that I want:

[image]

The difference is subtle, but basically I just want to shrink the graph.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838709/scale-and-size-of-plot-in-rstudio-shiny) may help

Comment: Yes I saw this, but it did not give me what I want :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` argument in `plotOutput` can be used for that purpose. Then you can wrap the output in a `div` with central alignment.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'grey'))

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    plotOutput('plot1'),
    div(
      plotOutput('plot2'),
      style = "padding-right: 10%; padding-left: 10%"
    )
  ),
  function(input, output, session){
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot(gg)
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot(gg)
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: It's not the whole panel I want to shrink, just the ggplot